# How to get the image URL from html code using Java

Tags: java

Given a sample HTML below. How can I get the image link http://lis.deped.gov.ph/uis/assets/rev/2630813/images/deped-logo.gif`? 
Just in case the image link starts in`//`like`//uis/assets/rev/2630813/images/deped-logo.gif` I will just have to add a string before it.

How to do it with regex? I do not want to use http library.

```
 <div class="navbar-header"><button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#deped-uis-nav-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button><span class="navbar-brand"><img class="logo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7HKA.gif" alt="DepEd" style="height: 20px; margin-top: -2px"></span></div>
```

Comment: Depends if you have a big html code with a lot of image. In that case, use a XML parser. Otherwise, you should use regex -like `src="//(.*?)"` )

Comment: Perhaps regex would work?

Answer (score 3):

You can use JSoup for this..

Refer the below code.. you need to add the JSoup library to make this work.

```
    String html = "<html>your html code goes here</html>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements image = doc.getElementsByTag("img");

     for (Element el : image) {
       String src = el.absUrl("src");
       System.out.println("src attribute is : "+src);
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

No need of library for that, use a regex because it's a simple operation and your program should be as lightweight as possible

Smething like:

```
src="//(.*?)"
```

Then, use Java `String` [replaceAll(String regex,
                String replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) with your rebuilt String.